FOR LOOP not working so it doesn't insert data into table
Ok, so, here's the code
DECLARE
    v_remessa_id NUMBER;
    v_count NUMBER;
    v_nm_remessa VARCHAR2(50);
BEGIN

    SELECT COUNT(*) + 1 INTO v_count FROM TB_REMESSA;
    v_nm_remessa := 'REMESSA ' || v_count;
 
    INSERT INTO TB_REMESSA (NM_REMESSA, REGISTRO_REMESSA, STATUS, LOCAL_ENTREGA)
    VALUES (v_nm_remessa, SYSDATE, 1, :P3_SELECT_LOCAL_ENTREGA)
    RETURN REMESSA_ID INTO v_remessa_id;

FOR C_ACEITOS IN (
    SELECT
        tbsol.SOLICITACAO_ID,
        NM_SOLICITACAO,
        tpsol.TIPO_SOLICITACAO,
        tprol.PROTOCOLO,
        REGISTRO,
        locrec.LOCAL_RECEBIMENTO
    FROM TB_SOLICITACAO tbsol
    INNER JOIN
        TB_TIPO_SOLICITACAO tpsol ON tbsol.TIPO_SOLICITACAO_ID = tpsol.TIPO_SOLICITACAO_ID
    INNER JOIN
        TB_PROTOCOLO tprol ON tbsol.PROTOCOLO_ID = tprol.PROTOCOLO_ID
    INNER JOIN
        TB_STATUS_SOLICITACAO stsol ON tbsol.STATUS_ID = stsol.STATUS_ID
    INNER JOIN 
        TB_LOCAL_RECEBIMENTO locrec ON tbsol.LOCAL_RECEBIMENTO = locrec.LOCAL_RECEBIMENTO_ID
    WHERE
        stsol.STATUS_ID = 2
    AND
        locrec.LOCAL_RECEBIMENTO = :P3_SELECT_LOCAL_ENTREGA
    ) 
    LOOP

        INSERT INTO TB_SOLICITACAO_REMESSA (SOLICITACAO_ID, REMESSA_ID)
        VALUES (C_ACEITOS.SOLICITACAO_ID, v_remessa_id);

    END LOOP;
END;

The problem is, the LOOP part is not working, it doesn't insert into the table, i've tried so many things and can't find the problem
Debugging it didn't give me any information. there's no error at all, i can't find out.

Welcome to Stack Overflow! Have you checked if :P3_SELECT_LOCAL_ENTREGA contains the expected value and that the SELECT ... FROM TB_SOLICITACAO tbsol part returns data?

Thank you! Yes, the SELECT part returns data. I don't know if that's a useful info, but for context :P3_SELECT_LOCAL_ENTREGA is a SELECT LIST

Basic debugging - that can be very frustrating but as a developer you have to go through it. We cannot this debug this for you since we don't have access to your code. Start by adding APEX_DEBUG calls to your code. Those can be reviewed when you run the page in debug.
Plausible causes are

the loop does not have any iterations.
you cannot see the data that is inserted for some reason

Start by verifying the loop has iterations, for example with some statements like below.
DECLARE
    v_remessa_id NUMBER;
    v_count NUMBER;
    v_nm_remessa VARCHAR2(50);
BEGIN
    apex_debug.info( p_message => 'Process: Start, P3_SELECT_LOCAL_ENTREGA: %0',
                     p0        => :P3_SELECT_LOCAL_ENTREGA);
    SELECT COUNT(*) + 1 INTO v_count FROM TB_REMESSA;
    v_nm_remessa := 'REMESSA ' || v_count;
 
    INSERT INTO TB_REMESSA (NM_REMESSA, REGISTRO_REMESSA, STATUS, LOCAL_ENTREGA)
    VALUES (v_nm_remessa, SYSDATE, 1, :P3_SELECT_LOCAL_ENTREGA)
    RETURN REMESSA_ID INTO v_remessa_id;

FOR C_ACEITOS IN (
    SELECT
        tbsol.SOLICITACAO_ID,
        NM_SOLICITACAO,
        tpsol.TIPO_SOLICITACAO,
        tprol.PROTOCOLO,
        REGISTRO,
        locrec.LOCAL_RECEBIMENTO
    FROM TB_SOLICITACAO tbsol
    INNER JOIN
        TB_TIPO_SOLICITACAO tpsol ON tbsol.TIPO_SOLICITACAO_ID = tpsol.TIPO_SOLICITACAO_ID
    INNER JOIN
        TB_PROTOCOLO tprol ON tbsol.PROTOCOLO_ID = tprol.PROTOCOLO_ID
    INNER JOIN
        TB_STATUS_SOLICITACAO stsol ON tbsol.STATUS_ID = stsol.STATUS_ID
    INNER JOIN 
        TB_LOCAL_RECEBIMENTO locrec ON tbsol.LOCAL_RECEBIMENTO = locrec.LOCAL_RECEBIMENTO_ID
    WHERE
        stsol.STATUS_ID = 2
    AND
        locrec.LOCAL_RECEBIMENTO = :P3_SELECT_LOCAL_ENTREGA
    ) 
    LOOP

        apex_debug.info( p_message => 'Process: In Loop, remessa_id: %0',
                         p0        => v_remessa_id);
        INSERT INTO TB_SOLICITACAO_REMESSA (SOLICITACAO_ID, REMESSA_ID)
        VALUES (C_ACEITOS.SOLICITACAO_ID, v_remessa_id);

    END LOOP;
    apex_debug.info( p_message => 'Process: Start');

END;

Run the page in debug, check what is happening and then continue debugging.

I'm new in oracle apex, i know where to see the debug, but i can't find those messages in the debug page. Are they suppose to show there?

Yes. Enable debug, perform the action that runs this process, open debug (make sure you're looking at the debug from the page this process runs on) and look for the message. If the message is not there... is the process fired at all ? Are there serverside conditions or build options on it that yield false ?

Google "how to debug an apex application" - there are a lot of sources on it

Ok, thanks for the tips! I'll try.

Don't use COUNT(*)+1 to generate a sequence; use a SEQUENCE.
CREATE SEQUENCE TB_REMESSA_SEQ START WITH 1234; 

(Start with whatever number would be the next number in the sequence.)
Don't use loops, use INSERT INTO ... SELECT:
DECLARE
  v_remessa_id TB_REMESSA.REMESSA_ID%TYPE;
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO TB_REMESSA (
    NM_REMESSA,
    REGISTRO_REMESSA,
    STATUS,
    LOCAL_ENTREGA
  ) VALUES (
    'REMESSA ' || TB_REMESSA_SEQ.NEXTVAL,
    SYSDATE,
    1,
    :P3_SELECT_LOCAL_ENTREGA
  ) RETURN REMESSA_ID INTO v_remessa_id;

  INSERT INTO TB_SOLICITACAO_REMESSA (
    SOLICITACAO_ID,
    REMESSA_ID
  )
  SELECT tbsol.SOLICITACAO_ID,
         v_remessa_id
  FROM   TB_SOLICITACAO tbsol
         INNER JOIN TB_TIPO_SOLICITACAO tpsol
         ON tbsol.TIPO_SOLICITACAO_ID = tpsol.TIPO_SOLICITACAO_ID
         INNER JOIN TB_PROTOCOLO tprol
         ON tbsol.PROTOCOLO_ID = tprol.PROTOCOLO_ID
         INNER JOIN TB_STATUS_SOLICITACAO stsol
         ON tbsol.STATUS_ID = stsol.STATUS_ID
         INNER JOIN TB_LOCAL_RECEBIMENTO locrec
         ON tbsol.LOCAL_RECEBIMENTO = locrec.LOCAL_RECEBIMENTO_ID
  WHERE  stsol.STATUS_ID = 2
  AND    locrec.LOCAL_RECEBIMENTO = :P3_SELECT_LOCAL_ENTREGA;
END;
/


If the INSERT "doesn't work" then debug your code and make sure that the SELECT you are using generates rows and if it doesn't, then fix the SELECT. (We cannot help with that because you have not provided any way of recreating the problem.)

I tried your code and only the INSERT INTO TB_SOLICITACAO_REMESSA didn't work. All table names are correct, i don't know the problem to be honest.

I tried creating data directly from Object Browser and i got that error: ORA-02291: integrity constraint (CIPTEA.TB_SOLICITACAO_REMESSA_REMESSA_ID) violated - parent key not found What can it be?
